# Printing with thermal printers via usb - Flutter

Tags: flutter, printing, usb, thermal-printer, flutter-windows

I am developing a Flutter app, and I’ve been trying to print via usb in a thermal printer. I have found a lot of libraries/package for bluetooth thermal printers, but I need my program ALSO works via USB.

I only have found one package that allows me to print in almost any printer, the name of the package is “printing”, but this works whit PDF’s, and the thermal printer doesn’t allow print PDF’s.

Note: The app I am developing is for Windows.

Does someone know some package or method I can try to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a comment but I don't yet have enough reputation. However, I have faced a similar issue recently attempting to print to a thermal receipt printer that is USB.

The only solution I found was to create a flutter plugin with native windows code and use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/winspool/. There is the win 32 package that could do the same thing https://pub.dev/packages/win32.

Hopefully someone else may have a better solution, but that is something to look into.

Comment: I've already connected the printer via Bluetooth, the problem is the packages of Flutter for this purpose are only for Android and IOS, nothing for Windows. I've tried to do a native code, but I can't find a good tutorial about printing in Windows in thermal Printers, and join this with flutter.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into [quick_usb](https://pub.dev/packages/quick_usb) to connect to the printer via usb

Answer (score 0):

I have created a package that might solve your problem:

usb_thermal_printer_web: This package helps you to connect to your thermal usb printer via USB in Flutter Web and print. It has been tested in MP583 thermal printer.

https://pub.dev/packages/usb_thermal_printer_web

Answer (score 0):

- This package allows connection with usb devices for android and windows
- flutter_pos_printer_platform: ^1.3.2
- Here is the repo : https://github.com/arthas1888/flutter_pos_printer_platform

As VDTe pointed out the link above is discontinued.
How about using this link or one of the forks?
https://github.com/TFSThiagoBR98/flutter_pos_printer_platform

Comment: Sadly this has been discontinued